# Перетаскивание изображений с компьютера в область на сайте

Tags: jquery, drag-n-drop, javascript

Проблема в том, что когда я перенашу фОТО, то она открывается в новом окне.

```
 dropBox.addEventListener('dragenter',function(){
    return false;
},false)
dropBox.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    displayFiles(dt.files);
    return false;
},false)
dropBox.addEventListener('dragleave',function(){
    return false;
},false)
dropBox.addEventListener('dragover',function(){
    return false;
},false)

function displayFiles(files) {
for(var j=0;j<files.length;j++){
    var file = files[j]

    if(file.type.search(/image/) == '-1'){
        return false;
    }

  var li = document.createElement('li')
  var img =document.createElement('img')
  li.appendChild(img)
  imgList.appendChild(li)

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load',function(aImg){
      return function(e) {
      aImg.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      aImg.setAttribute('height', '94');
      /* ... обновляем инфу о выбранных файлах ... */
    };
  }(img),false)

  reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
}
```

}

Но если назначить обработчики через jquery, то все работает нормально

```
 dropBox.bind({
dragenter: function() {

  return false;
},
dragover: function() {
  return false;
},
dragleave: function() {

  return false;
},
drop: function(e) {
  var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  displayFiles(dt.files);
  return false;
}
```

});

Comment: jquery это библиотека js, вы бы сделали fiddle или посмотрели в консоль...

Comment: проблема в том, что через JS открывается изображение, которое я перенес туда. А консоль следовательно изменяется сразу. Хром и Винда 7 у меня

Comment: >А консоль следовательно изменяется сразу.
простите что ? (наверное очищается, так ткните иконку - не очищать консоль)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно браузер не поддерживает?
Также попробуйте вместо return false использовать e.preventDefault()

Вот кусок моего кода (проверено в chrome)

```
File.setUploadZone = function(element,url) {

        element.addEventListener('dragover',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                element.addClass('dragOver');
        },false);
        element.addEventListener('dragenter',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                element.addClass('dragOver');
        },false);
        element.addEventListener('dragleave',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                element.removeClass('dragOver');
        },false);
        element.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();                     
                element.removeClass('dragOver');
                File.upload(e.dataTransfer.files,url);  
        },false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Выбор файлов с помощью перетаскивания](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-dnd)